# How do I get 1 million people in a region?

Tags: simcity-4

What do you have to do to get 1 million people in a region (and is it even possible)?

My cities seem to stop growing when reaching 100k people. After I reach this number of people, all my buildings become abandoned and demand for industry, housing and commercial buildings stall. People also complain about long commute times, while having 2 Highways surrounded by avenues and a very dense metro network.

I've built Police stations, elementary schools, high schools, universities, hospitals, a municipal airport, a stock market, mayor statues, churches... I've got a positive cash flow and my mayor rating is very high. All my commercial zones, industry zones and housing zones are of the highest possible density. I don't have any agricultural zones. So, you guys got any advice for getting more people into my city?

Comment: This seems like a very broad subject to cover in our simple Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

Even on a large map it is possible to get close to 1 million so if you talking about a whole region this should be easy. Your question however is too broad, you are actually asking for the full mechanics of a game in a single question.

Starting small is key especially if you are new to the game. Zone some commercial, around it some low/medium dense residential and lay down a road or avenue to the other side of the map and zone some industrial there. There you also build a powerplant, coal is cheapest. On a empty (none polluted) area of the map you build a water pump. Now connect the two area's with water and electricity and you should start making money.

Only build those service buildings that cost money if you can afford it unless you can go bankrupt. I always build police stations last, your city can even run without them perfectly fine. While zoning keep in mind where you want to put up rails for public transport, maybe even a highway or monorail when you got the money.

If you start to have around 40-50K people in the city you are able to construct very tall buildings with high density zoning. Just a couple of these residential buildings can flood your schools and hospitals, it's best to start these out of the range of your service buildings. This way they bring you pure income.

Tall buildings need breathing space, so leave some room open inbetween them, fill that with parks, buss stops, metro stations, tennis courts, flower gardens, etc. if you have the money.

Don't be afraid to start on new maps next to it. Connecting these cities will boost demand. I often start with two maps, on one i just build dirty industry, electricity and a garbage dump on the map next to it i build residents and commercial and let them pay for the electricity by making a electricity connection between the city. This works very well but the "dirty" city that supplies power and garbage space will get more money then the city you will need it in with all the residents.

When you hooked up 6+ grown cities you can start building those cities with a huge core of commercial with on the outside residential. Perhaps in the corners high tech industry. This is when you will start getting lots of inhabitants. Just a couple of these cities should take you too 1 million.

There is a ton to learn in between these steps, you are welcome to put up "smaller" question here. You can also watch my video's on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz8UfUhksUM) i also have a serie without speech that covers more of the basics through annotation, it's my first series.

Finally, some advice. Do not zone those boring 4x4 grids, they may seem the most efficient but they are boring. Without mods most parts of the city won't even develop since the buildings do not have breathing space. Try to make interesting neighborhoods, it's much more fun.